# Can I connect a BNC output of DVR to the antenna input of a LED TV?

Tags: video, input, output

I have a DVR and a LED TV. The DVR provides 2 video outputs, VGA and BNC but the LED TV only accepts 2 possible video input (HDMI and antenna socket).

In my mental model, as the BNC output of DVR and the antenna input uses coaxial cables, they should work if they are connected.

Can I connect BNC output of DVR to the antenna input of a LED TV?

EDIT:

[The manual of DVR](http://www.uksecurityshop.co.uk/product-files/avtech/4ch/674/kd67x_4_manual.pdf).

[The LED TV specification](http://www.samsung.com/sg/consumer/tv-audio-video/television/led-tv/UA32EH4003MXXS-spec).

Comment: This question will likely get closed since it is about consumer electronics and not electronics design or so. But the manuals might give you an answer. So please share your part numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the two connectors may be similar looking, or even identical, the signals need not be identical or compatible. The documentation sets for the respective devices provide  specifics about the two interfaces:

- The specified TV does not have an *antenna* input, but an RF In (*Terrestrial/Cable* input). **Edit**: This should be able to accept either a cable or antenna input, neither relevant to the problem at hand. (*Thanks Chris Stratton*)
- The TV also has a Composite In (AV) according to the manual, **which is not mentioned in the question**, but which should work for you, see next point.
- The specified DVR does not have an RF modulated output as would be needed for the RF in above, but the BNC is Video Out (**composite video** signal 1 Vp-p 75Ω BNC), which you should be able to feed to the Composite In of the TV.

---

In general, connector type matching is not sufficient indication of compatibility between devices:

- DVR coaxial output is typically either RCA composite signal, or RF modulated output - the latter would be labeled as such, or described thus in the manual.
- Most modern TVs with a coaxial (analog) **RF input** typically support an RF signal from an antenna - if they have an integrated TV tuner.

However, a solution might exist using the composite signal input and output on the two devices.

Comment: Not quite true, that is an "Antenna" input, "Terrestrial" referring to ground-based transmitter frequencies as opposed to those used for satellite TV.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So would signal levels be the same as for an antenna? If so I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: No, but the RF input is designed to accept either a cable or an antenna signal as a consumer would typically have in their home.  A studio-type digital TV modulator might output a higher power than the antenna input can handle, but a consumer wouldn't normally encounter one of those.

Comment: "RF encoded composite signal" is mistaken terminology, composite is baseband, not RF modulated yet.

Comment: Wrong fix; the consumer is not going to get a high-level RF signal, but they might get a high level composite one.  And antenna signals are not high impedance - twinlead was 300 ohms, but coaxial is only 75, same as the characteristic impedance of the cable used.

Comment: This answer has one redeeming merit - the discover of the composite input jack.  Other than that, it's chock full of inaccuracy, and lacks an engineering-quality understanding of the subject material.